# Maximum length of a string that has no substring divisible by a prime number $p$ is $p-1$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

> What is the maximum length of a string of nonzero digits that has no substring that is divisible by a given prime number?

I want to find a string of length **n** which has no substring divisible by the given prime number **p** (the string cannot have zeroes). I coded in c++ and for some prime numbers **p** I noticed the following property:

The maximum length possible for that desired string is **p-1**. Does that property hold for every prime number?

These are the prime numbers that I have tested:

**2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13**

For all of these prime numbers **except 2 and 5**, length of the longest string which has no substring divisible by that prime number is (that prime number - 1 ). For example for 13 we have string **"111112115541"** which has no substring divisible by 13. Length of this string is **12** and my code says there is no such string with length **13**. So **12** is maximum.

I can't check this for **17**. Because my code takes very time to execute and cannot realize that property is correct or not. Actually I have found the desired string for **17** with length **16** and if my code says that there is no such string with length **17** then that property is also holds for **17**.

BTW For all prime numbers **p <= 97** my code has found that desired string with length **(p-1)**. But I don't know that this length is maximum or not. I'm only sure about **3, 7, 11, 13** .

Comment: Can the string have zeroes?

Comment: @barto No. Sorry!. Strig cannot have zero.

Comment: @barto: Any zero in the string would constitute a substring divisible by $p$ (since everything divides $0$).

Comment: @Lnxdx: What does your search code say for $p=101$? I can vaguely imagine a systematic construction of length-$(p-1)$ strings that might get in trouble for the first time at $p=101$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm i found a string of length 95 for p=101

Comment: @HenningMakholm and it's running for length=96.

Comment: @HenningMakholm ans answer for length=96 also found. But takes 36.234 seconds to execute.

Comment: Hmm, so we won't learn that a length-100 string _doesn't_ exist that way. I withdraw my request. (Or does $p=101$ seem to be significantly harder than $p=97$?)

Answer (score 4):

**Upper bound.** If $p$ does not divide $10$, then there can be no such string of digits longer than $p-1$.

Namely, consider all *suffixes* of your string (including the empty string) and compute the remainder of each of them (interpreted as a number) modulo $p$. If the string is longer than $p-1$ then there are more than $p$ different suffixes; by the pigeonhole principle two of them will have the same remainder. Subtract them! You get a number of the form $b\cdot 10^n$ where $b$ is a substring of your original string, such that $p\mid b\cdot 10^n$. Since $p$ doesn't divide $10^n$, it must divide $b$.

Comment: And this generalizes to any integer $p$ coprime to $10$!